# How multiple function declaration at a time works?

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    void foo(), f();
    f();
}

void foo()
{
    printf("2 ");
}

void f()
{
    printf("1 ");
    foo();
}
```

**Output:**
`1 2`

How the declaration is working here?
And if I define F() before foo() I am getting error.

**Wrong!**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    void foo(), f();
    f();
}  

void f()
{
    printf("1 ");
    foo();
}

void foo()
{
    printf("2 ");
}
```

**ERROR**

```
> main.c: In function 'f': main.c:21:13: error: incompatible implicit
> declaration of function 'foo'
>              foo();
>              ^ main.c:7:18: note: previous implicit declaration of 'foo' was here
>              void foo(), f();

              ^
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Basically what went wrong here, you could already have learnt from the answers to the very similar question that you asked previously. Please try to digest the answers that you receive first, before posting a new one.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of scope. In the first example, `foo` and `f` are known to main because you declared them. `f()` knows `foo` because it's declared before it.

In your second example, the declaration of `f` and `foo` being local to main, `f()` doesn't know `foo` because it wasn't declared before it.

Answer (score 2):

The error message my compiler gives is "implicit declaration".

You declared the functions `f()` and `foo()` as `void`, **in the scope of main**.  You then use them outside of that scope (namely, you call `foo()` from inside `f()` - and `f` is declared outside of `main`).

The compiler treats this encouter with `foo();` in the second line of `f()` as "the first time I heard of this function" - since it is no longer in the scope of `main`, it has forgotten everything it was told while it was in the `main` scope (including "the return type of `foo()` and `f()` will be `void`). Absent any information, it will assume that `foo()` returns an `int`. When it finally comes across the definition of `foo`, lower down in the code, it realizes that it was wrong about its assumption. But rather than quietly fixing it, it complains.

That's C for you.

If you put the declaration before `main()`, your problem goes away:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(), f();

int main(void)
{
    f();
}  

void f()
{
    printf("1 ");
    foo();
}

void foo()
{
    printf("2 ");
}
```

Thus - the problem is not the "multiple declaration" of your function (as you implied in the title of your question) - it is the *scope* of the declaration that is causing trouble.

Answer (score 1):

It's called "forward declaration". Check google for the details, but in your case:

```
void f();
void foo();
void f() { foo(); }
void foo() {}
int main { f(); return 0; }
```

Comment: what is the meaning of this?

void foo(), f();

Comment: just tells the compiler the functions will be defined later.

Comment: so we can declare as many functions as we want by separating them with comma?

Comment: Yes, usualy you write the declarations to the headers .h files

Answer (score 0):

You can redeclare something as many times as you want as long as they have the exact same declaration. For example the following is valid:

```
void foo();
void foo();
void foo();
```

However, `void foo();` and `foo();` aren't the same. The latter implicitly defaults to `int foo();`. This is why you need to define `foo();` before you call it or it will get treated as a redeclaration/new declaration.